# to get to only matched data

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

i have two tables in which master table has already dense ranked upon id and stored in master table. now i want to match the master table to other table based upon other column  and without disturbing the ranking in master table and append the matched from other table , but the problem i am getting is first i am using dense rank on the id and after dense ranking using the other coulmn where the existing rank are going off, and i getting new rank.i want to do this process for five columns

i tried union all and dense rank , when i am doing this whenever i am order by new column the rank is changing for the data based on the order by condition

Comment: I don't understand. Sorry. Please show your query. Show some sample data and the expected result, so we get a better idea of what you are doing and trying to achieve.